# VSC Conda Enviroments - Can select interpreter but kernel remains always at base

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, environment

(This is the first time I am asking a question on Stack Overflow, so apologies in advance if I am breaking a convention).

**Context:**
I am using a work laptop with VSC, Anaconda (22.9.0), and Python (3.9.13) installed. I have created an environment to work with geospatial datasets using anaconda prompt `conda create -n spatial_env python=3.9`

**Issue:**
When I open VSC I can't seem to get out of the "base" environment. What seems odd is that I can find and select the desired environment as an interpreter (ctrl + p, select interpreter). The interpreter path also correctly matches the environment's python exe location.  Nonetheless, selecting the environment does not appear to affect the environment in use in the kernel. This is not affected by restarting the kernel or even VSC.

I have also tried opening VSC via the Anaconda Navigator after first having selected an environment. Oddly, the environment then shows up in the terminal at the bottom of VSC, however, the kernel relentlessly stays put on base.

I am quite confused to why this may be the case. While VSC Anconda Enviroment problems have frequently been posted on stack overflow, I haven't been able to find a solution that works among the existing posts. I would greatly appreciate any insight to what might be going on, or direction to other useful posts on this topic that I might have missed. Below I I have attached some screenshots for clarification.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqv6e.png)

I tried:

1. selecting the desired interpreter (ctrl + p, select interpeter)
2. opening the environment and VSC via anaconda prompt
3. edit the default interpreter path in json, setting  the `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"`  from `C:\\Users\\Public\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nwm39\\venvlauncher.EXE`  to
   `C:\\Users\\Public\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nwm39\\python.exe`

My expectation is that the kernel would change to the specified environment, but it stays put at base.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The **Select Interpreter** panel is to select the interpreter for the `.py` file. If you want to change the jupyter kernel, click the kernel version in the upper right corner of the jupyter notebook interface and select it.

[image]